# How do you create a dynamic copyright year in the footer using SXA?

Tags: sxa

I'm looking to build a new site and want to make the copyright something Content Editors do not have to worry about.

Is there a way in SXA to automate the year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this solution:

1. Static html (requires Content Editor).
2. Static html with JavaScript to update the year.
3. Scriban template to calculate the year on render.
4. NVelocity *could* be used but is no longer available with SXA.

For now we'll focus on 2 and 3.

### Static html with JavaScript

Add a Rich Text or Plain HTML rendering to the Partial Design for your footer with the following text:

```
<div class="copyright"></div>
```

Add a script to your theme with something like this:

```
(function ($) {
   'use strict';

   $(function () {
        var theDate=new Date();
        var year = theDate.getFullYear();
        $('.copyright').append("<p>©" + year + " Michael West, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>");
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

### Scriban template

Add a new Scriban template to whichever component you want with the following text:

```
<p>&copy; {{ date.now.year }} Michael West, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
```